# SQL EDITOR OPTIONS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008, sql-scripts

Apologies in Advance for this question.

I have visual studio with reporting services 2008 R2. Editing SQL can be a pain when not formatted correctly. I have to do this in design mode in reporting services mainly and it is difficult to read.

What are the options of having access to a toll that can help me write SQL scripts using the colour schemes, commenting and intellisense? I do not have access to SQL Management Studio. Is there a lite version that will allow me to do this or is there any other software that will help me with writing SQL easily?

Many thanks,

W

Comment: Heidisql might be worth a look - though I don't see the problem with ssms which is free anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just using SSMS? It's a free download, you don't need a lite version. It's SQL Server that costs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

If you want to practice development at home then you can also sign up to Visual Studio Dev Essentials which is free for personal use and will allow you to practice your skills. You also get access to other tools and some training to help you.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-dev-essentials-vs.aspx

If you're sure you don't want SSMS then you could always use Notepad++ which should do the formatting that you're after.

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/